# unity startcoroutine not work in start

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

Hi, This is my code.

The Unity through PHP code connects with mysql.

```
public string userLoginFile = "localhost:8088/database/Userlogin.php?";
string username = "****";
string password = "****";
string Name;
 bool InfoTest = false;
string family;
string status;
 Text we;
 Text st;
public void Start(){
    GameObject inputUsernameFiled = GameObject.Find ("usernameInput");
    GameObject inputPasswordFiled = GameObject.Find ("passwordInput");
    GameObject welcomeQ = GameObject.Find ("welcome");
    GameObject statusQ = GameObject.Find ("status");
    we = welcomeQ.GetComponent<Text> ();
    st = statusQ.GetComponent<Text> ();

    InputField In1 = inputUsernameFiled.GetComponent<InputField> ();
    InputField In2 = inputPasswordFiled.GetComponent<InputField> ();


        //st.text = "Your Account Is Saved!";

    if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("InfoCheck") == 1){
        username = In1.text;
        password = In2.text;
        we.text = "Welcome To Golden3 Service!";
        //st.text = "Your Status Is: " + status;
    }
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("InfoCheck") == 2){
        username = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UsernameIs");
        password = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PasswordIs");
        StartCoroutine (LoginUser (username, password));
        st.text = "Your Account Is Connect!";
        we.text = "Welcome "+ Name +" To Golden3 Service!";
        Debug.Log (Name);
    }
}

void Update(){
    //Awake ();
}

public void OnClick(){
    if(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat ("InfoCheck") == 1){
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("UsernameIs", username);
    PlayerPrefs.SetString ("PasswordIs", password);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat ("InfoCheck", 2);
    StartCoroutine (LoginUser (username, password));
    if(InfoTest == true){
        st.text = "Your Status Is: Connectet";
            Debug.Log (Name);
    }//end if

    }//end if
}// end click function

 IEnumerator LoginUser(string user, string pass){
    WWW login = new WWW(userLoginFile + "username=" + user + "&password=" + pass);
    yield return login;

    if(login.error == null){
        InfoTest = true;
        Name = "test";
        /*
        string[] credentials = login.text.Split('/');
        foreach (string str in credentials){
            string[] cred= str.Split('=');

            for(int i =0; i< cred.Length; i++) {
                if(cred[i] == "name")
                    Name = cred[i+1];
                if(cred[i] == "family")
                    family = cred[i+1];
                    status = "Logged In!";
            }

        }*/
    }//end if
}//end login user
```

When in start function calls startcoroutine, Does not work

But when I click on the button, startcoroutine Works!

please help me!

thanks.

Comment: Did you debug it? I quess not ;) Just use Debug.Log and check what is going on - also I am not sure what do you expect from Start - it will be called only once - in the begining of GameObject life - no more.

Answer (score 0):

- There are two reasons possible for calling co-routine at start method
- It couldn't reach that code to Call Coroutine in Start
- Invalid url due to wrong values on username and password

```
     if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("UsernameIs")){
       username = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("UsernameIs");
     }else{
        username="****";
    }
    if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("PasswordIs")){
        password = PlayerPrefs.GetString ("PasswordIs");
    }else{
        password ="****";
    }
```